Remove Duplicate pandas with condition
I'm trying to remove duplicates from the below dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame({'id_SAP_transaction': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                    'checkout_security': ['2023-12-15', pd.NaT, 
                                          '2023-12-01', pd.NaT, 
                                          '2023-11-30'],
                    'nopol': ['AA123', 'BB456', 'CC789', 'DD101', 
                              'EE234']})

processed_df = process_dataframe(df.copy())

I want it to:

Preserve the date if the id_Sap is duplicated but on the checkout_Security is NaT.
If the checkout_security only has NaT select one of it
If on the checkout_security is all date, choose the latest date.

Here is my code:
def process_dataframe(df, no_date_value=pd.NaT):
    """Processes the DataFrame for duplicate removal and checkout_security handling.

    Args:
        df (pandas.DataFrame): The DataFrame to process.
        no_date_value (pd.NaT): Value representing a missing checkout date.

    Returns:
        pandas.DataFrame: The processed DataFrame.
    """

    try:
        # Ensure 'checkout_security' is datetime
        df['checkout_security'] = pd.to_datetime(
            df['checkout_security'], errors='coerce')

        # Sort by checkout_security (descending, NaT last)
        df = df.sort_values(by='checkout_security',
                            ascending=False, na_position='last')

        def handle_duplicates(group):
            # If there's at least one valid date
            if not group['checkout_security'] is pd.NaT:
                print(group)
                idx = group.index[0]
                return group.loc[idx]  # Return the row using the index

            else:
                first_row = group.iloc[0]
                return first_row
        # Remove duplicates based on 'id_SAP_transaction'
        df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='id_SAP_transaction', keep='last').apply(
            handle_duplicates, axis=1)

        return df

    except (ValueError, KeyError) as e:
        print(f"Error during DataFrame processing: {e}")
        return df  # Optionally, return partially processed DF
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {type(e).__name__} - {e}")
        return df  # Optionally, return partially processed DF

This is the expected result:
0                  
1  2023-12-15  AA123 
2                   
2  2023-12-01  CC789 
4                 
3  2023-11-30  EE234

But I got this:
0                   
1        2023-12-15  AA123 
2          
2        2023-12-01  CC789 
4                   
3        2023-11-30  EE234 
1                   
2               NaT  BB456
3                
3               NaT  DD101

How can I get my desired result?

Please try this
# Step1. Sorting by id_SAP_transaction and checkout_security
df = df.sort_values(['id_SAP_transaction', 'checkout_security'], ascending=[True, True])

# Step2. Dropping Duplicates
df_temp = df.drop_duplicates('id_SAP_transaction')

